# The perfect button in WPF

Tags: wpf, button, margin

I'm working with an internal tool (that uses WPF). The XAML for a simple form contains this markup to represent a Cancel button (formatting adjusted for readability):

```
<Button
    Content="Cancel"
    Width="85"
    Height="22" 
    TabIndex="3"
    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
    Margin="0,45,8,0"
    x:Name="cancelButton"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    IsCancel="True" />
```

My issue with this code is that it explicitly set a `Width`, `Height` and uses `Margin` and `Horizontal|VerticalAlignment` for its appearance and layout. By setting these properties on individual controls it means:

- Buttons could be inadvertently styled differently. Where is consistent margin?
- Appearance is controlled by the application, not the system settings. What if there's a larger system font size? How would the button resize itself accordingly?

I've removed the attributes from the XAML and it already looks nicer (the XAML, that is; the button itself is visually ugly). In its stead I've added a common button style to my `ResourceDictionary`, but it still feels wrong because I'm hardcoding a specific size and magin for my buttons.

Is there any way to tell my buttons to use some kind of system-defined metric for buttons which respects system settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the Windows UI Guidelines specify a standard button width of 75px, so I would set `MinWidth="75"` in your style (but not `Width`).

Margins should be set on a per-element basis, with 7px between related controls, 11px between unrelated controls, and 5px between labels and their targets.  You shouldn't need to set that last one, as I believe the default Label style has 5px padding by default on all sides.